# How can I have a split background that is not 50 /50?

Tags: html, web, colors, background

I really want to make my background split 40/60 or maybe 30/70 but every command I try leads to my background being split 50/50. To be fair, I'm very new to HTML so I may be doing the wrong command (I'm using gradient). Any advice would be nice!

Comment: Please add some relevant code to your question indicating what you've tried so far, and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you trying to split two different gradients or two different images of gradients?